# How to secure an "unlock"ed address?

Tags: accounts, security

I am using Parity and testing a mining pool.  In order for the pool to work, I need to specify the --author address on the node running the pool software.

I also need to have the payee accounts for the individual miner unlocked from the command line on another node.

How do I prevent my ETH from being stolen from the unlocked accounts?

Comment: Not exactly a solution to your problem, but a common approach is to have two wallets a cold wallet, and a hot wallet. The cold wallet is mostly offline, it only connects to send funds to the hot wallet (this is secured with hardware wallets perhaps), the hot wallet when detect funds will immediately trigger the payment processing.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you for replying but that is a solution to a different problem.  These wallets have to stay unlocked to receive funds from the miner.  It must be a very common problem as I am not the first person to mine.

Comment: To receive funds you do not need an unlocked account, only to send payment you have to unlock it.

Comment: @Ismael  Of course you are right.  You actually only need the mining *pool* address unlocked because it pays the individual miners.  But the same question applies then.  How to keep that account safe if it is in "unlock" mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parity by default disables the UI on nodes with an unlocked account.  Leave it that way for security.  And don't allow public RPC access obviously.